# How to convert image from (32,32,3) to (1,3072)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

(Regarding image classification)

What is the easiest way to convert a 32x32x3 image to a 1x3072 array such that 1024 are red, 1024 are green and 1024 are blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using numpy: (`arr` is the image array)

```
swapped = np.swapaxes(arr,0,2)
flattened = swapped.flatten()
```

your array will be in `flattened`

Swapping between the first axis and the last, and then flattening the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
img = img.transpose(2, 0, 1)  # Depends on your original order
img = img.reshape(1, -1)
```

See:

- [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)
- [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)